# Scrapy - How can I handle a random number of elements?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a Scrapy crawler that I can comfortably acquire the first desired paragraph, but sometimes there is a second or third paragraph.

`response.xpath(f"string(//h2[contains(text(), '{card}')]/following-sibling::p)").get()`
 is the xpath code I am using to acquire said paragraph.

`response.xpath(f"string(//h2[contains(text(), '{card}')]/following-sibling::p[1])").get()` acquires the same paragraph, but sometimes, I need `response.xpath(f"string(//h2[contains(text(), '{card}')]/following-sibling::p[2])").get()`.

How might I go about taking this varying number of paragraphs into account when scraping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use a wildcard *.

*removed*

EDIT : With string() function you'll only get the first paragraph.

Just remove string() from your XPath expression to get all the paragraphs (assuming there are in the same node) and store the result in a variable.

```
//h2[contains(text(), '{card}')]/following-sibling::p/text()
```

Alternative : If you know the maximum possible number of paragraph, you can use concat().

```
concat(//h2[contains(text(), '{card}')]/following-sibling::p[1],'|',//h2[contains(text(), '{card}')]/following-sibling::p[2])
```

Comment: This jumps down past the second paragraph, past an h2, and into the first paragraph following the h2.

Comment: This `p[*]` means _"any `p` element having some element child"_ so it has nothing in common with abbreviated positional predicates like `[1]`

Comment: I just have edited my answer. Feel free to post the html code you're working with.